# how to add lines in UITextView programmatically

Tags: objective-c, ios, cocoa-touch, uiscrollview, uitextview

In my notebook application i need to add new note view. In the note view, `UITextView` has to enter new notes. I want the `UITextView` to:

- Insert (ruled)lines.
- When scrolling the `UITextView` the lines also should scroll with that entered text.
- When going to the next    line in `UITextView` it should automatically create the lines.

  How is it Possible?

[image: Image of Notebook app)]

As can be seen in the image above the white space is the `UITextView`. I Need to Add the below image (line with yellow background)

[image]